# Query to return 1 row of each duplicate

Tags: sql

I am using MS SQL 2008R2.  I am working with a partial data set (i.e. not all colunms) and have not been able to exclude duplicate rows.  For example, here are the rows for a claim:

```
Claim       Line Doctor Received    Paid
02195111345 1    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 1    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 2    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 2    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 3    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 3    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 4    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 4    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 5    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02  
02195111345 5    22924  1995-11-13  2001-10-02
```

I want to select only 1 row for each Claim+Line.  There are additional columns, but they contain the same information for each combination of Claim+Line.

I can easily identify the rows with duplicates with a query such as:

```
SELECT [ClaimNum],[ClaimNum_Line]
FROM [dbo].[DamagedClaims]
GROUP BY [ClaimNum],[ClaimNum_Line]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Typically, I would create a derived table using this query and join it back to the table - with another coulmn such as MAX(Version) or such, but there are no such columns with which to differentiate the duplicates.

I have considered

```
SELECT ClaimNum], Line, MAX(DOCTOR), MAX([Date Received]), MAX([Date Paid])
```

but there are about 20 columns and 750 million rows and that seemed like a lot of overhead (I am very sympathetic to our SQL Servers!).  Is there a better solution?

Best,
Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT Claim, Line, Doctor, Received, Paid
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 2):

I see no column that can be the basis of you maximum row, try using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tableA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT DISTINCT` - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp